# Magento contacts forms with multiple transactional emails templates

Tags: magento-1.9, php, forms, contact-us, contact-form

I want to have more contacts forms in my store and separate transactional emails templates for each contact form in part, for example:

- contact_form1.phtml with contact_form1.html email template;
- contact_form2.phtml with contact_form2.html;
- contact_form3.phtml with contact_form3.html;
- ....

I need to be like this because I want to have different variable in each email template.

I found this [Inchoo tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/) but I don't know how I can add multiple forms and email templates.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please let me know whether u are able to submit u r contact form in the frontend?

Comment: yes the contacts works fine in the frontend but I to add separate transactional emails for each one

Comment: for what is that?

Comment: Sorry @Reobert wrong screenshot. now please check this http://prntscr.com/fsctjg ?

Comment: here i am showing you dynamically creating the tabs and in the drop down showing u  new  templates which were created in the transaction emails http://prntscr.com/fsddto

Comment: yes I think is okay but how we can add that contactform1 ....

Comment: Hi @Robert please try the below steps please let us know u r  feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create a module using Sillk Software [Silk Software Module Creator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/)
and install the same.

> **Note:** Here i am considering the module called **Ewall_EmailTabTamplate**

**Step 2:**  Now do the changes in config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ewall_EmailTabTamplate>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ewall_EmailTabTamplate>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <emailtabtamplate>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Ewall_EmailTabTamplate</module>
            <frontName>emailtabtamplate</frontName>
          </args>
      </emailtabtamplate>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <emailtabtamplate>
              <file>emailtabtamplate.xml</file>
            </emailtabtamplate>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <emailtabtamplate>
        <class>Ewall_EmailTabTamplate_Helper</class>
      </emailtabtamplate>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <emailtabtamplate>
        <class>Ewall_EmailTabTamplate_Block</class>
      </emailtabtamplate>
    </blocks>
    <!-- Custom Htmls stars Here -->
    <template>
            <email>
               <sales_email_order_template translate="label" module="sales">
                    <label>ContactForm-1</label>
                    <file>sales/contactForm1.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </sales_email_order_template>
                <sales_email_order_tab_template translate="label" module="sales">
                    <label>ContactForm-2</label>
                    <file>sales/contactForm2.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </sales_email_order_tab_template>
                <sales_order_email_temp_analyzer translate="label" module="sales">
                    <label>ContactForm-3</label>
                    <file>sales/contactForm3.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </sales_order_email_temp_analyzer>
                <sales_email_order_email_temp_cabmaster translate="label" module="sales">
                    <label>ContactForm-4</label>
                    <file>sales/contactForm4.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </sales_email_order_email_temp_cabmaster>
                <sales_email_order_email_temp_cabvision translate="label" module="sales">
                    <label>ContactForm-5</label>
                    <file>sales/contactForm5.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                 </sales_email_order_email_temp_cabvision>          
            </email>
    </template> <!-- adding custom htmls ends here-->

  </global>
</config>
```

> Note: Clear Cache and session after modifying the xml file/s.

**Step 3:** Create contactForm1.html, contactForm2.html ... in the below path

```
app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/contactForm1.html
```

After html creation has been completed you will be able load the html files in the transaction emails from the admin end.

> Login to admin => System => Transactional Emails => Add new template
>   => Click on  load template

**Screenshot:** https://prnt.sc/fsddto

**Step 4:** Now coming to frontend contact us form in your custom template section

**For Example:** http://prntscr.com/fsqdri

Please keep the below code in the mentioned path: `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/emailtabtamplate/index.phtml`

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('emailtabtamplate/index/contactForm1'); ?>" id="contactForm1" method="post" 
class="scaffold-form">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone')) ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="tel" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment')) ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    //var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm1', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

**Step 5:** Now keep the below code in the index controller and contactForm1Action
`app/code/local/Ewall/EmailTabTamplate/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
<?php
class Ewall_EmailTabTamplate_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function IndexAction() {

      $this->loadLayout();   
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Titlename"));
            $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
           ));

      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("titlename", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Titlename"),
                "title" => $this->__("Titlename")
           ));

      $this->renderLayout(); 

    }

    // contactForm1Action code starts here

    public function contactForm1Action()
    {

         $myParams=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
         $customerName= $myParams['name'];
         $customerEmail= $myParams['email'];
         $telephone = $myParams['telephone'];
         $comment=  $myParams['comment'];

         /*
         $customerName= 'Custom Testing';
         $customerEmail= 'test@test.com';
         $telephone = '123456789';
         $comment='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged';*/

         $myCustomVars = array('customer_name' =>$customerName,
                        'customer_email'=>$customerEmail,
                        'customer_telephone'=>$telephone,
                        'customer_comment' => $comment
                        );

       $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
       $recepientName = "Custom Tester";                            
       $templateId = 1; // Template Id from admin end 
       $sender  = array(
                        'name' =>   'Custom Tester',
                        'email' => 'customemail@gmail.com'
                    );
       $recepientEmail = 'recepient@gmail.com';
       $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
       $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
       $mail->getMail()->addBCC('bccmail@gmail.com');
       $mail->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $myCustomVars, $storeId);
       $translate->setTranslateInline(true);       

       $this->_redirect('emailtabtamplate');//redirect url
       Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Successfully Sent'); 

    }
    // contactForm1Action code ends here

    public function contactForm2Action()
    {
        //Keep the code as shown contactForm1Action


    }

    public function contactForm3Action()
    {       
         //Keep the code as shown contactForm1Action 

    }

}
```

**Step 6:** coming to passing custom variables passing to transactional email
Please find the screenshot. http://prntscr.com/fsqpln

We have to use the email variables like as shown below in your contactForm.html (or) related transactional email in the **Template Content** section

```
{{var customer_name}}
{{var customer_email}}
{{var customer_telephone}}
{{var customer_comment}}
```

**Output:** http://prntscr.com/fsqssw